# ChainLink: where does the data from when I call GetRoundData?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chainlink, aggregator

I am currently learning how to start developing on ChainLink, and I saw that there is a GetRoundData() method that is used to return data from a specific timestamp.

When I dig into the code and I found that there the method came from the interface AggregatorV3Interface. Also, I didn't find the implementation of the function inside any of .sol files, but I find it in a .go file.

My question is, how is the aggregator store data on the blockchain? as I see the data come from nowhere when I call getRoundData. If data comes from the module written by Go lang, does that means the data source is off-chain? Thank you.

Code snippet captures:
[aggregator_v2v3_interface.go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4nRq.png)
[AggregatorV3Interface.sol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVmSW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A contract implementing this interface is deployed on an address specified in the `_AggregatorV2V3Interface` Golang variable.

So your offchain script is connected to a node of some EVM network (Ethereum, BSC, Polygon, ...) and queries the node to perform a read-only, gas-free, [call](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call) on that specific contract address. The actual data is stored onchain.

Comment: Thank you, I also found the logic implementation on chainlink's repo (https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink) ./contracts/src/v0.4/Aggregator.sol.
The data is on-chain.